# Authentication Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am currently building an authentication server for a game. Basically how I have it planned out is a client will connect to our servers and they will authenticate the client and then issue the client a ticket. As long as the ticket is valid the client is able to join servers. Besides authentication I would like to display user stats and other stuff on their profile. I have not done anything with ASP.NET before but I think that is the right way to go on this. I was wondering if anyone knows where I might get started with communication with an ASP.NET web app. Is that too big of a step since I haven't used ASP.NET before? Should I start with something smaller?

**EDIT:**
Ok so I have a simple WCF Service now but I am having trouble understanding exactly how to use it. How do I actually use the service I created to exchange data between a console app and a ASP web site? Anyone know of a tutorial that creates a WCF service then actually shows how to implement it into a project?

Comment: Start by learning how to write a simple WCF service.  It's really pretty straightforward these days (.NET and Visual Studio to a tremendous amount of the heavy lifting for you).

Comment: "It's really pretty straightforward these days " - could still be alot simpler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of game? Is it a game played on your website or a client application? If it's a website then all you really need is a Login page. Otherwise, yeah WCF.

Comment: It is on a stand alone client but yeah I am looking into WCF now.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use someone else authentication server. I.e. Facebook, Messenger (Live.com), Google all provide OAuth authentication if you can agree to use their list of users.

Side benefit is that you don't need to worry a bit less about personal information (i.e. child accounts require much more care that you want :) ).